# Hall subgroup that has normal complement

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $H$ be a Hall subgroup of finite group $G$. If $H\leq Z(N_{G}(H))$ then $H$ has a normal complement in $G$.

I want to know if we assume $|H|=n $, is $H$ the only subgroup of $ N_{G}(H)$ of order $ n$?

Or is the below statement true for Hall subgroups?

"Let $H$ be a Hall subgroup of the finite group $G$. Also assume that $a,b \in C_{G}(H)$. If $a,b$ are conjugate in $G$, then they are conjugate in $ N_{G}(H)$."

If one of the two is true I can answer the main question. Otherwise, how can I solve the main question?

Comment: Any two Hall $\pi$-subgroups are conjugate, and you know $H$ is normal in $N_G(H)$.

Comment: @user10354138 Don't you need to assume the group is solvable to have all Hall $\pi$-subgroups be conjugate? Or am I misremembering which parts of those theorems require solvability?

Comment: @user10354138 in the way you say we need $G$ be solvable.

Comment: oops, sorry, forgotten about that part.

Comment: As I commented on the (now deleted) MO question, if $H$ is a normal Hall subgroup and $K$ is a subgroup such that $|K|$ divides $|H|$ then $K\leq H$ (just consider the subgroup $HK$).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft yes,I saw that but in the main question $H$ is only hall subgroup ,we don't know it is normal or not

Comment: One part of your question asks whether it is the unique subgroup of its order in its normalizer, which is the part I was answering.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thank you.